# Unable to build nav2d_karto

Tags: ros, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to build nav2d_karto using catkin_make, I get the following error:

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CSPARSE_INCLUDE_DIR
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
used as include directory in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto
CSPARSE_LIBRARY
linked by target "mapper" in directory /home/matt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d/nav2d_karto

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/matt/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/matt/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:9292: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

I can't seem to fix it.  Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273038/unable-to-build-nav2d_karto/) by [Matt31](https://answers.ros.org/users/32243/matt31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you donot install csparse, try to install it.

---

Originally posted by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) with karma: 26 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matt31](https://answers.ros.org/users/32243/matt31/) on 2017-10-20**:
How do you install csparse?  That seems to be just some script file.

**Comment by [l_a_den](https://answers.ros.org/users/17996/l_a_den/) on 2017-10-22**:
Try install `libcsparse`  relative package.